# ASP.NET MVC 5 jQuery AJAX master/detail table

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What I'm looking for is pretty simple but it's evading me, and I'm not able to find a good example anywhere.

I've got an MVC Razor loop of entities:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="stockIndexLink">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="componentRow">
        <td id="componentCell">
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In jQuery, I want to load the detail PartialView into 'componentCell', sort of like so:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#componentRow").hide();

            $("#stockIndexLink").on("click", function () {
                $("#componentRow").slideToggle(300, function () {
                    $("#componentCell").load('@Url.Action("GetStockIndices", "AdminStockIndex", new { id = 1 })');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

...as you can see, I've hard-coded the id value into the Url.Action just to see it do *something*. How do I get that id from each row, into the "click" event, without an ugly hack? Also, I know I have some work to do on that hide and toggle stuff...but I can handle that. The id is what's tripping me up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could put the url in the anchor href tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetStockIndices", "AdminStockIndex", new { id = item.Id })" class="stockIndexLink">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</a>
```

and in jQuery:

```
$('.stockIndexLink').on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        url = $this.attr('href');

    var $componentRow = $this.closest('tr').next('.componentRow');
    var $componentCell = $componentRow.children('td').first();

    $componentRow.slideToggle(300, function() {
         $componentCell.load(url);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT: Also note, as explained in some of the other answers that have the same id on multiple elements is against html spec so I have changed the jQuery objects to search for classes.  Also updated so it doesn't select all component rows and cells.  (From @Stephen Muecke's answer)

Comment: I was half way through posting a solution using a `data-id` attribute when this answer appeared, but this is a much cleaner approach. Good call.

Comment: Still not correct - this would update every row in the table with `class="componentRow"`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes (`id="stockIndexLink"` and `id="componentCell"` which means that you could only ever do anything for the first row anyway. You need to use class names. The easiest way is to store the `Id` property as a `data-` attribute and retrieve it in the `.click()` event

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="stockIndexLink" data-id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    ....
</tr>
<tr class="componentRow">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

}

Then you script should be

```
$(".stockIndexLink").on("click", function () {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var componentRow = $(this).closest('tr').next('.componentRow');
  var componentCell = componentRow.children('td').first();
  componentRow .slideToggle(300, function () {
    componentCell .load('@Url.Action("GetStockIndices", "AdminStockIndex")',  { id = id });
  });
});
```

Comment: New to jQuery, had no idea class selectors were capable of this. Thanks for the explanation. Will definitely be studying up on this!